# Is this a rifle or a shotgun?

Tags: specifications, firearms

According to a Meta Post I found this is the right place to ask this kind of question. I apparently can't find the post anymore but it pointed towards this subsite.

Yesterday I had an argument (for almost an hour) over whether in the end of Season 1 Chapter 2 of the Walking Dead game, this character called Andy was holding a rifle or a shotgun.

To show it there's two screenshots on imgur and a walkthrough video which is set to the specific time frame where the gun gets shown.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFmXu.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM3Sb.jpg

https://youtu.be/_zjJqegIG8c?t=7456

Here are my arguments that show that it's clearly a rifle:

- There's only one barrel
- There's not enough place for slugs and loading extra ones
- The "carving-in" is for holding the rifle
- The understock looks like a rifle's
- The muzzle and sound look and sound like a rifle's
- There's a loading chamber for a rifle with the pulling thingy

The arguments for a shotgun:

- Supposedly it has a shotgun loading mechanism
- There is supposedly a compartment for the slugs, even though it's so thin
- Sound doesn't matter, because the game designers made it so

We agreed upon the fact it's a rather old gun and definitely not a modern one.

My questions would be:

- So which one is it?
- What kind of model is it (if it's not fictional?)

Comment: why are you asking here about a video game developer's choices?

Comment: @jsotola I am not asking about that, the opposite party only specified that as an argument, hence I'm just quoting that opinion

Comment: you are at an engineering website, asking a question about an imaginary device after you wasted an hour of your life arguing about the same ... only the game developer would know for sure, but this is not a place to be asking

Comment: @jsotola my guess is that the developer had a specific REAL firearm in his head when designing my asset and hence my question here.

Comment: you are not talking about a physics simulation ... you are talking about a game with zombies ... that is already disconnected from reality ... anyway, opinion based questions are off topic here

Comment: Well, the video game in question obviously is not that sci-fi to that far from reality to feature completely unrealistic future weaponry, so yeah... The question may sound opinion-based but the answer would be fact based.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be specific and answerable. If you want to know the difference between the two types guns, that could possibly work. Asking about a video game does not fit within the topics of this site. You may get a better answer at a video game, movie, or scifi portion of the Stackexchange network.

Comment: Off topic here. More on topic on Movie and Sci-Fi SE.

Comment: I already got an answer with which I am more than satisfied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's neither or both or whatever you want

Evidence for rifle:  It's drawn like a bolt action rifle with a small magazine

Evidence for Shotgun: The barrel is large like a shotgun

Evidence for neither:  It's handled like a semi-automatic rifle (action wasn't cycled after the shot); there isn't room to eject a shell from the action; and the bolt cycle wouldn't be enough to put an actual shell into the action either manually or through the magazine.

This is a made-up weapon made up by people for whom accuracy wasn't a concern.

Answer (score 1):

From 2:04:20 to 2:04:21, there is a large spark (white then turns red) coming out of the barrel, does this tell something? It looks like a shotgun to me.

[image]

Comment: The spark in the screenshot is blue?..

Comment: The inner circle is bright white, which is enclosed by blue light in a star shape, then turns to red in the next second. The important thing is it reveals the gunpowder used and initing mechanism, which are different for the two.